# MySQL Group results

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, items.category, customers.sector
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN items ON items.customer_id = customers.id
GROUP BY items.category, customers.sector
ORDER BY customers.sector ASC
```

Gives me this result:

```
| count |         category      |    sector    |
|-------|-----------------------|--------------|
|   3   |   A-Frames & Trolleys |   Automotive |
|   4   |      Suction Mounts   |   Automotive |
|   1   |         Hand Cups     |   Automotive |
|  103  |       Glazing Tools   | Construction |
|   2   |   A-Frames & Trolleys | Construction |
|   2   |     Suction Mounts    | Construction |
|_______|_______________________|______________|
```

I want the sector column to be unique and to show the category with the biggest count
eg:

```
| count |         category      |    sector    |
|-------|-----------------------|--------------|
|   4   |      Suction Mounts   |   Automotive |
|  103  |       Glazing Tools   | Construction |
|_______|_______________________|______________|
```

Thanks

Comment: So you want the `MAX(COUNT())` for each `sector`?

Comment: yes that's what I'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select max(count) as `count`,
       substring_index(group_concat(category order by count desc), ',', 1) as category,
       sector
from (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, i.category, c.sector
      FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
           items i
           ON i.customer_id = c.id
      GROUP BY i.category, c.sector
     ) t
group by c.sector;
```